# memory of drawables, is it better to have resources inside APK, outside APK or is it the same for memory?

Tags: android, memory, drawable

I have an application that draws a lot of graphics and change them.
Since I have many graphics, I thought of having the images outside the APK, downloaded from the internet as needed, and saved on the files application folder.

But I started to get outOfMemory exceptions.

The question is:  Does android handle memory different if I load a graphic from APK than if I load it from 'disk'?

code using APK:

> > topView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);

code if image is outside APK:

> > Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
> >     topView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, internally they are handled the same. Most likely, you're leaking the images, or not cleaning them up as quickly as you could. Try calling `Bitmap.recycle();` once you're done with an image, to force Android to clean it up.

Comment: wait, what? you're leaking the images? Can you please expand on this... this doesn't sound like something that Google would just skim over... are you saying loading a local Drawable into memory creates a situation where unless you manually release the memory, it won't be GCed on its own?

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, the memory footprint you're seeing should be about the same no matter which way you load it.  Android will use a utility to byte-align resources internal to the apk which should improve loading times.